# How to edit a keyboard layout for a language in Xubuntu?

Tags: keyboard, xubuntu, keyboard-layout, language-support, input-language

I want to edit the keyboard layout for the language Nepali. That's for fixing a weird inconvenience.

The way the layout works is that every key is assigned a non aspirated Nepali consonant and by pressing the key with `Shift`, you get the aspirated versions. Except, not with the key 'C' for some reason. The expected output from it would be 'च'(t͡s) and pressing 'C' with `Shift` should give 'छ'(t͡sʰ) but no, it's the opposite.

So, how do I fix it and get rid of this problem? And, why is it like this in the first place?

Answer (score 1):

For such a small change I would suggest that you simply open the `/usr/share/X11/xkb/symbols/np` file for editing and make the desired change.